# How to autofill multiple fields on form repeater rows in Laravel with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a form repeater set up in a Laravel project with multi-field and I need the fields to automatically fill data based on the first field's selection.

My first row is working fine, however the autofill is not working on the rest of the rows.

Here is my code. Am I missing something or did I do something wrong somewhere? Would appreciate some assistance in solving this riddle.

Relevant code from my controller:

```
public function getProducts(Request $request){

      $search = $request->search;

      if($search == ''){
        $products = Product::orderby('product_code','asc')->select('id','product_code','product_name','product_price','product_min_price')->limit(5)->get();
      }else{
        $products = Product::orderby('product_code','asc')->select('id','product_code','product_name','product_price','product_min_price')->where('product_code', 'like', '%' .$search . '%')->limit(5)->get();
      }

      $response = array();
      foreach($products as $product){
        $response[] = array(
          "value"=>$product->product_code,
          "label"=>$product->product_name,
          "price"=>$product->product_price,
          "minprice"=>$product->product_min_price
        );
      }

      return response()->json($response);
    }
```

The repeater view HTML:

```
<form class="form repeater-default">
                <div data-repeater-list="group-a">
                  <div data-repeater-item>
                    <div class="row justify-content-between">
                      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
                        <label>Product Code</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_code">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
                        <label>Product Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_name">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
                        <label>Product Price</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_price">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
                        <label>Product Minimum Price</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product_min_price">
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group d-flex align-items-center pt-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-repeater-delete type="button"> <i class="bx bx-x"></i>
                          Remove Product
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col p-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-repeater-create type="button"><i class="bx bx-plus"></i>
                      Add Product
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
```

The JavaScript for the autofill in my view:

```
<script>
    
    var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $( "#product_code" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
          
          $.ajax({
            url:"{{route('vendor.estimates.getProducts')}}",
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
              _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
              search: request.term
            },
            success: function( data ) {
              response( data );
            }
          });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
          // Set selection
          $('#product_code').val(ui.item.value);
          $('#product_name').val(ui.item.label);
          $('#product_price').val(ui.item.price);
          $('#product_min_price').val(ui.item.minprice);
          return false;
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```

The JavaScript for my form repeater:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
  // form repeater jquery
  $('.file-repeater, .contact-repeater, .repeater-default').repeater({
    show: function () {
      $(this).slideDown();
    },
    hide: function (deleteElement) {
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
        $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
      }
    }
  });

});
  </script>
```